# How to listen to click in while loop

Tags: java, android, while-loop, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a view (button) and am listening to a click event, but in my while loop it won't call the `onClick` method:

```
public class Activity_Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1); 
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_1:
                //do something make boolean false for example
                break;
        }
    }

    while(boolean == true) {
        //it's not reacting on the click
    }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: No you missed nothing. This can not work. Put the loop in a thread.

Comment: Get rid of the loop, and initiate whatever action you need to in `onClick()`.

Comment: What are you doing before and in the while loop, and what is the button supposed to do?

Comment: I'm recording and playing audio from the mic. If I place it in a thread, how do I stop the recording (that's what the button is supposed to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread with that infinite `while` loop:

```
while(boolean == true) {
    //it's not reacting on the click
}
```

and it cant execute any other code. You should be more worried about the ANR coming next rather then the click not responding. Put the `while` loop in a separate thread as suggested and dont overload the main thread's work with excessive tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Handlers and Messages you can start and stop the recording when the user clicks the button. And to check if the button has been clicked, just use onClick method.